# Cleaning up after variable declaration, initialization and unamanaged memory allocation

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to kindly ask for your advice on a good programming practice in c# when it comes to defining variables, allocating space for them, initializing them and then properly cleaning up everything.

The problem I am facing at the moment is, that I have a function which uses unmanaged API functions and as a result also accesses unmanaged memory (Marshaling is used). I would like to make the function clean and properly dispose of everything before exiting. The thing is though, that all actual work is done inside a *try-catch* block. Which means that I can not clean everything in a *catch* or *finally* block.

What I've done is declare all variables, reserve memory for them and initialized them right after entering the function and then clean everything up (close handles, release memory,...) in *finally* block.

All good but I would also like to have variable declaration, initialization and memory allocation done in a *try* block (something can also go wrong when initializing an array for example or allocating space in memory or God knows where). The only thing which comes to mind is nesting two *try-catch* blocks. Is this OK or would you propose something else?

Here is what I have so far:

```
//Declare variables, allocate memory, initialize variables.
........
try
{
    //Do actual work - write to file and read from a file in my case
    .........
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    //Exception handler for file write/read errors
}
finally
{
    //Clean up (release handles, free memory,...)
}
```

And here is what I have in mind:

```
try
{
   //Declare variables, allocate memory, initialize variables.
   ........
   try
   {
       //Do actual work - write to file and read from a file in my case
       .........
   }
   catch (Exception exc)
   {
       //Exception handler for file write/read errors
   }
}
catch (Exception exc_1)
{
    //Exception handler for variable declaration, initialization, memory allocation errors
}
finally
{
    //Clean up (release handles, free memory,...)
}
```

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `IDisposable` interface in order to call Dispose method.

Or as best practise use block `using`

```
using (var variable = .....)
{

 ...

}
```

The particularity of using block is that call Dispose Method in the end of treatment.

For example if you use `SqlConnection`

```
var(var connection = new SqlConnection("...."))
{
....

}
```

Just this code is sufficient

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/system.idisposable.aspx

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: This won't work for me I think. Some examples of what I would like to have in the outer most try-catch:

'NativeOverlapped HidOverlapped = new NativeOverlapped();'
'IntPtr eventObject = CreateEvent(IntPtr.Zero, false, false, "");'
'IntPtr nonManagedOverlapped = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(HidOverlapped));'
'Marshal.StructureToPtr(HidOverlapped, nonManagedOverlapped, false);'

I am also initializing one of my array's elements.To be on the safe side I also have to assume a possible error while doing this (for example an IndexOutOfBounds exception).

Any thoughts?

Comment: How about using a separate function for doing the work (reading and writing to file)? This way this new function would have its own try and catch block. 
But would program return to the caller function if exception would be thrown and handled by the catch block in the called function?

Comment: 1 you can add try catch inside your block using  2 set using block arround your nonManagedOverlapped, and that's good

Comment: Be warned - the using statement is syntactic sugar for try-finally therefore if you wanted to catch an exception that occured within the using statement it would need to be encapsulated by it's own try-catch.

Comment: @Jamie: I just read a bit about the using statement and came to the same conclusion as you. At compile time a using statement gets expanded to try-finally. So using a using inside a try-catch is in fact nesting try-catch blocks. Am I correct?

Comment: That's correct, you would effectively have try{ try-finally }catch()

Answer (score 0):

Problem with that approach is variable is out of scope in the finally (and catch)

```
    try
    {
        string testString;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        // testString is not in scope
    }
```

Your concern is that the declaration may throw a run time error?

Based on comment OP is not aware initialization can be separate from declaration.

```
    List<string>  testLString;        
    try
    {
        testLString = new List<string>();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        testLString = null;
    }
```

I don't agree with your concern that a declaration might throw a run time error.
It does nothing but declare.

Comment: That is exactly my concern. And since I am also initializing variables (not only declaring them), I am concerned an error might pop up there.
To put it simple, I would like to "split" the function in two parts:

1) Prepare everything needed to do work (declare and initialize variables, structures and whatnot; prepare everything in the unmanaged part of memory,...)
2) Do actual work

I would like to have both parts "covered" for exceptions.

Comment: You do know you can initialize separately from declaring?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest as many `try...catch` structures as you want or need. It's a good way to make the code take responsibility for its own cleanup.

Consider also using a structure with just `try` and `finally` for code that always needs cleanup, regardless of whether it went ok or not:

```
try {

  // do something here

  // declare some variable
  try {
    // allocate space for variable
    // do something with that variable
  } fincally {
    // deallocate space for variable
  }

  // do something more here

} catch(Exception ex) {
  // handle the exception here
}
```

You should try to use an exception class that is as specific as possible, and you can use different types in the same structure to catch different exceptions:

```
try {
  // do some i/o
} catch (IOException ex) {
  // here you know that it was actually the i/o that failed
} catch (Exception ex) {
  // here is for catching anything else that might have failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to create a separate type which wraps all the communication with the unmanaged APIs, manages memory etc. It implements the `IDisposable` interface the implementation of which takes care of cleaning up all unmanaged resources. If you are on Windows, the cleanest way to accomplish this is to implement this wrapper in C++/CLI.